# Automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

I'm looking for a description of  $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z})$.

I've tried an unsuccessfully combinatorical approac, does anymore have some hints?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the operation on $\Bbb Z\rtimes\Bbb Z$? I ask, because the direct product is also a semi-direct product, but I suspect that you aren't thinking of that.

Comment: @CameronBuie, I don't think there are many options here: for the semidirect product to be non-trivial (i.e., a non-direct product), it must use the only non-trivial automorphism of $\;\Bbb Z\;$ : $\;n\mapsto -n\;$ .

Comment: @Don: Fair point.

Comment: So the group is given by $\langle a,b : bab^{-1} = a^{-1} \rangle = \langle a,b : aba=b\rangle$. This is the fundamental group of the Klein bottle. Also known as the Baumslag–Solitar group $B(1,-1)$. Perhaps this gives some hints for searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the group as $G=\langle x,t\mid txt^{-1}=x^{-1}\rangle$.

Exercise:
the automorphism group is generated by the automorphisms $u,s,z$, where $$u(x)=x,\; u(t)=tx,\quad s(x)=x^{-1},\; s(t)=t, \quad z(x)=x,\; z(t)=t^{-1};$$ check that it is isomorphic to the direct product of an infinite dihedral group (generated by $u,s$) and the cyclic group of order two $\langle z\rangle$. Deduce that the outer automorphism group is a direct product of two cyclic groups of order two, generated by the representatives of $u$ and $z$.

Hint: first check that $\langle x\rangle$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$ (warning: it is *not* the derived subgroup).

Comment: Don't you mean $u(t)=xt$?

Comment: No, I really mean $u(t)=tx$, but if you define $u'$ by $u'(x)=x$ and $u'(t)=xt(=tx^{-1})$ then $u'=u^{-1}$. So you can replace $u$ by $u'$ if you like.